# Can i use ampersand instead of front slashes with the vue router?

Tags: vue.js, navigation, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm making a VueJS tables component as a part of php web application. The app uses '/' for changing directories and '&' for navigating the web app. Is it possible that i use ampersand sign with the vue router or will I have to come up with a custom solution for navigation? Any reccomendations?

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '&',
        component: Table
    },
    {
        path: '&create',
        component: Create
    },
    {
        path: '&single&:id',
        component: Single
    },
    {
        path: '&edit&:id',
        component: Edit
    }
]
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Can you specify why it is necessary to do it like this?

Comment: The PHP project that would use the plugin is big and in development for  a while, the convention for the project is that it uses '/' for changing directories and '&' for navigation and params.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in this case. When using `vue-router`, all parent routes need a front slash. This isn't the case for child routes, as you can see in this example from the docs:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/user',
      component: User,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'profile',
          component: UserProfile
        },
        {
          path: 'posts',
          component: UserPosts
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Nevertheless you still need a front slash for the parent route, even if you just use one parent and else just child routes. Maybe you find a workaround for this case and provide the routes like:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/table',
        component: Table,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'create',
                component: Create
            },
            {
                path: 'single',
                component: SingleContainer, // Wrapper
                children: [
                    {
                        path: ':id',
                        component: Single
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'edit',
                component: EditContainer, // Wrapper
                children: [
                    {
                        path: ':id',
                        component: Edit
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And if you also name them like `name: 'create'` they can be called without a front slash like:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'create'}">Create</router-link>
```

But as I said, you still need to provide at least one parent route with a front slash in your `router.js`.

I did a little research if it maybe is possible to replace the ampersand in the url request server side. But the ampersand is a reserved character, as you can read here: [Reserved characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters)

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. It seems that we will have to set up custom routes using '&' on the php part of the application and I'm going to use[URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#browser_compatibility) to show a component depending on the route param